# Makes "Files" the default program to open folders

Tags: files, filemanager, default, thunar, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10, everything is great. I love it.

I downloaded Thunar File Manager because I want to use some of its features (mass renaming and etc). After downloading and installing it, it somehow changed the default File manager app to it instead of Ubuntu's default "Files" app.

Right now if I download something using firefox and click "Open Containing Folder" from the download page, it launches Thunar File Manager instead of Files.

How can I change it back to Files?

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your terminal:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus-folder-handler.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```